# How to get the selected element in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native

I have users listed in a `FlasList` and there is a button beside each one of them. When this button is pressed, it triggers a function called `following` that sends a request URL to an API endpoint (following) to retrieve the following users by the selected user.

Within this URL request, there should be included the selected `user_id` like this: `http://example/api/user_id/following'`. So it's only the `user_id` that would change every request depending on the selected user

Now I am struggling with **how to get the selected user**? 
Any thoughts or suggestions about that would be much appreciated

**following function :**

```
following(){
  return fetch(`http://example/api/${user_id}/following`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
  this.setState({
  isLoading: false,
  content: responseJson,
  });
  })
  .catch((error) =>{
  console.log(error);
  });
}
```

**render :**

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.content}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>
          {" "}
          {item.user.given_name +
            " " +
            item.user.family_name +
            "\n" +
            item.content}
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => this.following(item.user.user_id)}
        >
          <Text>Following</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => this.following()}
        >
          <Text>Followers</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )}
    keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
  />
</View>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this where you pass the user_id as a parameter of the function and the insert it into the url using a template literal?

Following function:

```
following(id){
  return fetch(`http://example/api/${user_id}/following`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
  this.setState({
  isLoading: false,
  content: responseJson,
  });
  })
  .catch((error) =>{
  console.log(error);
  });
}
```

render:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.content}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>
          {" "}
          {item.user.given_name +
            " " +
            item.user.family_name +
            "\n" +
            item.content}
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => this.following(item.user_id)}
        >
          <Text>Following</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => this.following(item.user_id)}
        >
          <Text>Followers</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )}
    keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
  />
</View>;
```

Comment: Which part of it didn't work? Did the function receive the id correctly and the fetch failed, or did the function receive undefined?

Comment: The function didn't receive the id, as i have done a debug the URL and it looks like this when the request sent `Debug http://10.0.2.2:3333/api/v0.0.5/user/${id}/following`.  However, I think a user_id value should be used a parameter instead of id as I can retrieve this value from the database. but first passing a value to the function isn't working for some reason !

Comment: Add a console log before the fetch is called, does the id come through to the function at all? Also, in the fetch string, did you replace the '' with ``?

Comment: So adding the debug before fetch would generate this `Debug http://10.0.2.2:3333/api/v0.0.5/user/666/following`. there is a value but it doesn't belong to any user tho

Comment: Right. Can you post what the ```item``` object looks like? Maybe the issue is that you're passing the wrong value?

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get what you are after, what do u mean how it looks like

Comment: So from what I understand so far, the issue is that the function is being passed the wrong value? Can you post an example of the item object so we can work out which value to pass as a parameter rather than id?

Comment: Ok, so that's how it looks like : `"user": {
      "user_id": 0,
      "given_name": "string",
      "family_name": "string",
      "email": "string"
    }` .. I have tried to pass this parameter `item.user.user_id` and then url would be `http://10.0.2.2:3333/api/v0.0.5/user/${user_id}/following`. but i get an error says can't find variable. so I don't know if i was doing right tho

Comment: Can you post all of your updated code so i can see what it looks like?

Comment: Your following function should be ```following(user_id){}``` instead of ```following(){}```

Comment: Oh you're right, I have forgotten to do that. It worked finally. Thank you a lot. appreciate it